# View OCFS2 online nodes using command line?

Tags: ocfs2

I want to see which nodes is currently online in my OCFS2 cluster, how can I accomplish it using command line tools?

- **OCFS2 Tools:** 1.8.0-10.el6
- **UEK Kernel:** 2.6.39-400.264.4.el6uek
- **OS:** CentOS 6.7

Comment: @EEAA I searched through the [OCFS2 1.6 Users Guide](https://oss.oracle.com/projects/ocfs2/dist/documentation/v1.6/ocfs2-1_6-usersguide.pdf), [OCFS2 1.2 FAQ](https://oss.oracle.com/projects/ocfs2/dist/documentation/v1.2/ocfs2_faq.html) and Googled "ocfs2 view online node"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo mounted.ocfs2 -f
```

[overview of all ocfs2 tools](https://oss.oracle.com/projects/ocfs2-tools/documentation/v1.4/)